# What is this code doing besides get date?

Tags: javascript

I read this code on amazon's home page.
Looks like it's trying to get the current time, However what's the meaning of using operator `||+` ?

```
var ue_t0=ue_t0||+new Date();
```

Comment: If `ue_t0` doesn't exist set `ue_t0` to `+new Date()`, otherwise set it to `ue_t0`

Comment: so +new Date() is a function differs from new Date()?

Comment: @JrChen: prefixing "+" unary operator converts it to a number. e.g. `var a = '1'; var b = +a;`.

Comment: This is something you can easily check in your browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [short-circuiting evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (`||`) followed by [conversion to number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) (`+`).

That code is roughly equivalent to:

```
var ue_t0;
if (!ue_t0) {
    ue_t0 = Number(new Date());
}
```

Note that converting a date to a number returns the number of milliseconds between the epoch (January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC) and that date.

Comment: so +new Date() is a function differs from new Date()?

Comment: @JrChen, yes, the unary `+` operator converts its operand to a number as a side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying :

> evaluate ue_t0 and if it has value, then use it, else assign it
>   integer form of `Date` instance.

Answer (score 1):

It says let `ue_t0` be the value of `ue_t0` or, if it is undefined, the value of the expression (new Date).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `||+` operator in JavaScript, it is `+new Date()` which gives you a date representation in UNIX format

Answer (score 1):

There is no `||+` operator.

- `+new Date()` is a common shortcut to get the time as a timestamp. The `+` operator implicitly calls the `valueOf` method.
- The `||` operator is another common shortcut to set a default value (`+new Date()`) if a variable (`ue_t0`) is not defined (or equal to anything that evaluates to false : `null`, `0` ...).